"I've got a good voice, awful attitude."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 13)

'I'm Martin Mussey.' He strides ahead on sturdy legs. 'I've got a good voice, awful attitude. I'll never be head chorister, but I get plenty of solos.'

I take "awful attitude" to mean a cool, cocky, defiant, or arrogant manner (source MW). However, "awful attitude" could relate to "voice" there; but then I can't find any corresponding meaning. Maybe "awful attitude" is relating to the next sentence "I'll never be head chorister". That would make sense.

His bad (defiant, unhelpful, unco-operative) attitude towards other people means that he does poorly at co-operative activities (e.g. singing in a choir), but he is good at singing alone. Thus he will never be head chorister.

A head chorister is not merely the 'best' singer in a purely technical sense; he or she must be a good leader and able to encourage every member of the choir. Good diplomatic and interpersonal skills would be very important.

His bad (defiant, unhelpful, unco-operative) attitude towards other people means that he does poorly at co-operative activities (e.g. singing in a choir), but he is good at singing alone. Thus he will never be head chorister.
A head chorister is not merely the 'best' singer in a purely technical sense; he or she must be a good leader and able to encourage every member of the choir. Good diplomatic and interpersonal skills would be very important. (Michael Harvey)
